# Improving performance of Solr and MySQL pair (connected by "WHERE IN" using JPA)

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, solr

I have a MySQL database which is indexed by Solr. I carry out searches using Solr (fast), and I retrieve every result in the Solr search from the database using JPA. JPA runs a `WHERE IN` query on the database which is VERY slow.

Is there a way to make this process faster, or to refactor the design to improve performance?

I have just refactored the whole application from using MySQL's fulltext search to use Solr, and now the performance is worse.

Note: I need all results immediately to carry out calculations on, and thus, I cannot use pagination.

Java code:

```
    SolrDocumentList documentList = response.getResults();
    Collection<String> listingIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for(SolrDocument doc : documentList) {
        String listingId = (String) doc.getFirstValue("ListingId");
        listingIds.add(listingId);
    }

    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("getAllListingsWithId");
    query.setParameter("listingIds", listingIds);
    List<ListedItemDetail> listings = query.getResultList();
```

Named Query:

```
<query>Select listing from ListingSet listing where listing.listingId in :listingIds</query>
```

Additional Information:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE ListingSet` produces [shortened]:

```
CREATE TABLE `listingset` (
  `LISTINGID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTPRICE` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LISTINGID`),
  KEY `FK_LISTINGSET_MEMBER_MEMBERID` (`MEMBER_MEMBERID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_LISTINGSET_MEMBER_MEMBERID` FOREIGN KEY (`MEMBER_MEMBERID`) REFERENCES `member` (`MEMBERID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Investigating the generated SQL**

Looking at the generated SQL, JPA runs a lot of SQL queries for a single JPA query. The ListingSet table has 7 tables it is linked to, and runs a separate SELECT query for each table for EACH listingid (of which there are 1,000 - 10,000). So my one JPA query gets blown into what looks like ~7,000 queries!

Comment: The SQL-syntax would be: `Select listing from ListingSet listing where listing.listingId in (:listingIds)' ; given that listingIds is a comma-list.

Comment: JPA handles that. the query inside `<query>..</query>` is not a raw SQL query, but gets converted into the form you suggest by JPA.

Comment: I know that JPA does all kinds of things, but I expect your question could be answered just by looking at the generated SQL. In other cases, you'd have to consult the manual.

Comment: My issue was not confusion over what query was run. My question was what is the typical way of connecting Solr and MySQL such that there isn't very poor performance. I have seen the query that gets run by JPA, and it is the standard WHERE IN with a comma separated list of ids.

Comment: Well: look at the emitted SQL, or just add the parentheses and try. Maybe you even need to quote/unquote?

Comment: I know the query. I have tried it in MySQL workbench, it works fine except that it is very slow. The question is whether there is an alternative method of querying the database to obtain Solr results. Or an alternative method of producing results from Solr.

Comment: In that case it is a database optimisation problem anyway. Check the plan (how large is the commalist?). I rest my case.

Comment: The comma list is about 1,000 to 5,000  :(

Comment: Do you have an index on `ListingSet (listingId)` (shows us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ListingSet;`)? Can you provide the execution plan? (run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in Workbench or in command line and paste the output in the question).

Comment: Apologies, I was looking at the wrong log, and indeed, the JPA does a LOT more than a simple WHERE IN. It runs MANY queries to obtain related tables.

Comment: I have updated the question to include more info. Sorry, I was naive before to believe that I knew the SQL that was being run.

Comment: Should I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: I have answered the question. Your Comments were very helpful, but were not an answer in themselves. However, seeing as your comments helped me reach my answer, I don't mind giving you the bounty (assuming this is acceptable etiquette).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my use of JPA. Due to the many relationship my entity had, a single query exploded into 1,000-10,000 queries.

The solution is to use [Batch Processing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Batch_Fetching) in JPA to prevent the ORM n + 1 query problem. Batch processing causes JPA to request all relevant rows from related tables at once, rather than once for each entity. This solution is appropriate when a query returns *many* results, and the entity being queried has many relationships.

The easiest way to determine potential issues with JPA is to enable finer logging. For EclipseLink, add a property to `persistence.xml`:

```
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
```

Be wary that the logging produced under the default settings for EclipseLink only displays the JPQL form of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Following is just personal thoughts about debugging the problems:

- Turn on mysql query log
  and check the JPA not access MySQL every query for each listingId.

  mysql -uroot -pYOUR-PASSWORD -e "SET GLOBAL log_output = 'FILE'; Set GLOBAL general_log_file = '/tmp/mysql.log'; SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';"
  tail -f /tmp/mysql.log
- check if the performance is caused by MySQL, run the equivalent SQL in you MySQL database.

  Select listing from ListingSet where listingId in (put your real listingId here);

  Make sure has index on ListingId column (maybe very good chance is the index is already there)
- Since you only read the rows from MySQL, maybe you can setup Replicate for more slave,
  then split your ListingIds to all the slave MySQL, and merge the results afterwards.
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: ListingId is the primary key for the table, so it should already be indexed.

Comment: I have updated the question to include info from your suggested steps.

Comment: like i guess, It really access MySQL every query for each listingId.  how about using the `Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass)`